# Opencart . Методика верстки шаблона и создания

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, cms, opencart

Как интегрировать свою верстку в опенкарт? Обращался в гугл все материалы очень старые,  в оф документации одна страничка . Мб книга какая то, или туториал.

Answer (score 1):

структура front-end OC2:

```
-catalog
--controller (контроллеры)
--language (локализация)
--model (файлы моделей)
--view (представления)
---theme
----default (имя стандартной темы)
----your_theme (может быть кастомная тема)
-----templates
```

В последней папке лежат файлы представлений - вьюхи, в формате .tpl

Для админки так же, отличается лишь корневая папка и нет папки шаблонов по понятным причинам:

```
-admin
--controller (контроллеры)
--language (локализация)
--model (файлы моделей)
--view
---templates
```